# class instance cannot be reference inside IBAction method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ibaction

I am writing a small card game for iphone,

say, i have a player.h/.m class, which have a Mutable Array myCard

I write

```
@interface Player : NSObject{
    NSMutableArray *myCard;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myCard;

@end
```

in a view controller, controller.h

```
#import "Player.h"
@interface controller : UIViewController {
    Player *playerMe;
}
```

in a view controller, controller.m

```
 - (Player *)playerMe
{
    if (!playerMe) playerMe = [[Player alloc] init];
    return playerMe; 
}
```

then i have some instance method to addObject in playerMe.myCard, everything is fine till now.

I have a button which was added in IB, and have a IB action:

```
- (IBAction)btnSort:(id)sender {
    //do something with self.playerMe.myCard
}
```

Problem then appears, I look at the debug window and look up the value in all variables. Before the button was clicked, the self.playMe.myCard is fine with a certain object there. once the button was clicked, the self.playerMe.myCard is nil and have nothing inside

So, i would like to know why the self.playerMe.myCard cannot be reference while self.playMe is alright, is that about the @property definition?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you do inside - (IBAction)btnSort:(id)sender; when the button is clicked? Where do you initiate myCard?

Comment: alloc is called when the class player.m init

Answer (score 1):

Try to make explicit `retain` property for *myCard*. It may be a leak when using assign property by default.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myCard;
```

Comment: i tried, it dump EXC_BAD_ACCESS. actually, i only do a sorting and addsubview according to the playerMe.myCard array before button was clicked

Comment: btw, i dump the object self. self.playerMe, self.playerMe.myCard to the console. The first 2 has no problem. Just the self.playerMe.myCard dumped EXC_BAD_ACCESS. So, it should be about memory allocation, but can't fix it so far.........

Answer (score 1):

i finally solved the problem by changeing the @property attribut and a custom setter for myCard

player.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *myCard;
```

player.m

```
- (void)setMyCard:(NSMutableArray *)aCardArr
{
    [myCard autorelease];
    myCard = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:aCardArr] retain];
}
```

Maybe this is just basic stuff, but as a newer to objective-c, just post back here for someone like me as a reference.

Thanks for all of your help